# Time trigger doesn't work with CopyTo in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've this code in a google spreadsheet which works well when I run it with an interactive execution:

```
var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var original = originalSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("New");
original.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);
```

But if I run it with a time trigger it creates correctly the "New" spreadsheet, but the copyTo command doesn't copy anything of the original spreadsheet in it.

Have I made some mistake?

I use Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 and Chrome.

Comment: This does work for me. You should be looking at 'Copy of Sheet1' in the 'New' sheet.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above the sheet copy has a new name because Sheet1 exists by default when you create the spreadsheet. You can avoid this with a small change in your code. See code below

```
function test(){
  var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var original = originalSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("New");
  var defaultSheet = newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').setName('xxx');
  original.copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName('Sheet1');
  newSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(defaultSheet);
}
```

or, more simply, you can also copy the spreadsheet itself directly (if you want to copy the whole content of the original spreadsheet)

```
function test(){
  var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var newSpreadsheet = originalSpreadsheet.copy('new')      
}
```

This option will copy the script as well, the copy is a "clone" of the original.